# Java - Format number to print decimal portion only

Tags: java, numbers, format, decimal

Is there a simple way in Java to format a decimal, float, double, etc to ONLY print the decimal portion of the number?  I do not need the integer portion, even/especially if it is zero!
I am currently using the String.indexOf(".") method combined with the String.substring() method to pick off the portion of the number on the right side of the decimal.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?  Couldn't find anything in the DecimalFormat class or the printf method.  Both always return a zero before the decimal place.

Comment: Do you want to display the decimal point?

Comment: Yes, I want to show the decimal point

Answer (score 7):

You can remove the integer part of the value by casting the double to a long.  You can then subtract this from the original value to be left with only the fractional value:

```
double val = 3.5;
long intPartVal= (long) val;
double fracPartVal = val - intPartVal;
System.out.println(fracPartVal);
```

And if you want to get rid of the leading zero you can do this:

```
System.out.println(("" + fracPartVal).substring(1));
```

Comment: I believe that will still print the leading zero. I need it to print:  .5, not 0.5.

Comment: +1 this is new to me. here's another [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Obtainingtheintegerandfractionalparts.htm).

Comment: added in the way to remove the leading zero, but I believe it was more or less what you were already doing.  Subtracting to remove the integer part of the number should still be a more attractive solution though, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Divide by 1 and get remainder to get decimal portion (using "%"). Use DecimalFormat to format result (using "#" symbol to suppress leading 0s):

```
double d1 = 67.22;
double d2 = d1%1;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(df.format(d2));
```

this prints .22

Answer (score 0):

This will print 0.3

```
double x = 23.8;
int y =(int)x;
float z= (float) (x % y);
System.out.println(z);
```

Comment: This will work but it's unnecessarily complicated. Simply taking the remainder modulo 1 will do, or subtracting the whole integer part.