# printf to print decimal part only in java

Tags: java, decimal, printf

I want to print the real and decimal part of double number separately, without using strings or arrays concept? I don't know how to use printf() to print only decimal part.

input  1: 13.31432
output 1: 13
          31432

input  2: 15.36
output 2: 15
          36

I am able to print real part, but not able to print decimal part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5584237/1064610 and printf() is a c function

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println((long)input); //Prints real part
System.out.println(input - (long)input); //Prints decimal part
```

Comment: consider number 15.26 first line will print 15 but the second line still prints 0.26 instead of 26

Comment: double x = 13.31432d;
System.out.println((int) d); 
System.out.println(d - (int) d);

It gives output as :
13
0.3143200000000004

But i need output as :
13
31432

Comment: @PremKumarNaidu You can use substring to lop off the `0.`. E.g., `System.out.println(String.valueOf(d - (int) d).substring(2));`. I don't think there's a good way to remove the 00000000004 in the general case, as computers don't store floating-point numbers exactly. But if you know it's always five digits you want, you can do: `System.out.println(String.format("%.05f", d - (int) d).substring(2));` to get exactly `31432`.

Comment: @Boann: I don't want to use String or Array concept. Is it possible to get the decimal part without converting into String?

Comment: @PremKumarNaidu Another idea.. how about `System.out.println(String.valueOf(d).replace('.', ' '));` ?

Comment: Without using `String` somewhere you can not get the expected output. I'll try and will update my post if I get come clue.